# How to implement Search using azure-mobile-apps-js-client

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I have a hybrid cordova app which uses [javascript azure-mobile-apps-js-client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client) for communicating with server. Data is also synchronized in sqlite DB on device.

I need to implement search against Person entities by their Full Names.
All persons which matches search term(contains term inside Full Name) should be returned.
Something like "LIKE" in SQL.

I did read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library#table-filter) article but didn't found a way to do that.
Seems like this client is supporting only operations like =, >, <.

Does it mean I need to retrieve all records from table and filter them on client (which sounds weird to me) or I just missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an option to do that using javascript string.indexOf function.

```
//Declare a query
function queryFunction(term){
     return this.FullName.indexOf(term) != -1
}

//Pass it to where function
table
    .where(queryFunction, term)
    .read()
    .then(success, failure);
```

Comment: You have the right idea.  For full docs, see the API reference here: http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/global.html#QueryJs